# C++ application that uses Qt libraries stops working when screen saver starts

Tags: c++, windows, qt, crash, screensaver

I have a C++ application that uses some Qt libraries.
The application works fine until the screen saver pops up and starts.
After that if I quit from screen saver the application crashes and I have to re-start it again. I have tested the application on Windows 7 and XP and this happens on both.

Is there anything I can change in the code so this does not happen?

Comment: Does this occur on multiple systems or only your specific machine? Also, what OS are you working on?

Comment: It happens on multiple systems, it will happen in Windows xp and 7.

Comment: Start with with the debugger and get a backtrace of the crash.

Comment: @LucaCarlon has the answer. Q: "How do I debug this?"  A: "With a debugger of course!"

Comment: Well, quite clearly there's something wrong in code, which gets executed when screensaver activates or deactivates... Have you tried minimizing/unminimizing, does that work? Anyway, if it crashes, that should make debugging easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luca Carlon give you good and fairly popular advice -- use debugger. In your case, you can get a lot of information about debugging from [official documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/creator-debugging.html).

When you run debug of your program, you must replay situation when your program falls: you must manually start screensaver, or hurry up screensaver to start.

When your program fails -- get back-trace, and try to understand, what was wrong.